# How to use cli53 to add a svr record to route53

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

I have an aws amazon ec2 instance with cli53 installed. (if you don't know what this just looks it up).

I'm not great with Linux, and even worse with creating scripts.

I found a script that'll update a route53 zone automatically on startup (which is what I am looking for)

I'm looking for the proper command using cli53 to update/create an SVR record in my zone, as the server that would be running this command would run it after starting up to be a 'backup' for a downed server.

I hope that made sense. Let me know if you have questions, and I'll respond with the best answer!

Comment: You might get better results here if you try it, first.  Create the record in the console, then use `aws route53 list-resource-record-sets` to see how the cli formats the record you created, then use `aws route53 create-resource-record-sets --genetate-cli-skeleton` to build a boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to use the command to just update a cname record, and have the cname inside of an srv record. Should accomplish the same thing i'm trying to do.